# create join with many to many table in linq

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first

I have two tables students and lessons tables. I made a many to many connection in entityframeworkcore code first. When I run migration it created automatically a join table LessonStudent table. Holds studentId and LessonId. But I need to get all students with lessons using Linq. Efcore 5 is using. I find find any common thing between student and lesson table.

```
 public List<Student> GetAllStudents()
        {
            using (context db= new context())
            {
                var result = from s in db.Students
                             join l in db.Lessons
                             
                             on s.Lessons.FirstOrDefault() equals l.LessonCode
                             select new 
                             {
                                lessonCode = l.LessonCode,
                                studentAge = s.Age,
                                studentName = s.Name
                             };
                             
            }
        }
```

```
    public class Student
    {

        public int StudentId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Lesson> Lessons { get; set; }
    }
```

```
    public class Lesson
    {
        public int LessonId { get; set; }
        public string LessonCode { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
    }
```

Edit solution

I did it with this solution. If anyone wants to solve like this problem answer below. EFcore 5.0 did all mapping this

```
            select new Student                                                
          { Lessons = s.Lessons, Age = s.Age, Name = s.Name }; 
          return result.ToList();
```

Comment: So you want to return all students except the ones that don't take any lessons?

Comment: no I want to return all students with their lessons, even if they dont have lessons @GoodNightNerdPride. And Also I cant find where LessonStudent  table is. and how to reach it

Comment: Please provide a concrete example illustrating the input data and expected output data.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is `db.Students.SelectMany(s => s.Lessons, (s, l) => ...)`.

The query expression equivalent is using multiple `from` expressions:

```cs
var result =
    from s in db.Students
    from l in s.Lessons // relevant change here
    select new 
    {
        lessonCode = l.LessonCode,
        studentAge = s.Age,
        studentName = s.Name
    };
```

Working example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/GLTtfa

Comment: Unfortunately it is not the result I want to get it. For example your example results is I have one student but there are 5 lessons. It brings 5 records. For example I have one student if student registered one lesson. It needs to bring one record

Comment: @newUser What do you expect in that one record? Only the first lesson?

Comment: I have one student in student table and 5 lessons. but student have only two lessons. When I want to get all students result must be student firstlesson, student secondlesson. Must return two rows.

Comment: @newUser I'm still not sure I understand your requirements, but to me this implementation does exactly what you are asking for. Check this working example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/GLTtfa
If not then please provide a concrete example with input and output data. This back-and-forth is getting tedious.

Comment: @newUser, maybe this is what you are asking for: https://dotnetfiddle.net/GuEHtO